# OnClick event is giving compilation error in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having error in `LinkButton` tag when I am putting `OnClick` event in it.

```
 <asp:LinkButton ID="btngo" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("Blog_ID") %>' Text="More" Font-Size="Smaller" OnClick="btngo_Click" ForeColor="#3366cc"></asp:LinkButton>
```

and in code behind I have the code like this

```
protected void btngo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int id = int.Parse((sender as LinkButton).CommandArgument);
        Response.Redirect("Blog-Post.aspx?BID=" + id);
    }
```

and it says

`CS1061: 'ASP.blog_aspx' does not contain a definition for 'btngo_Click' and no extension method 'btngo_Click' accepting a first argument of type 'ASP.blog_aspx' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Any solution?

Comment: Are you sure your aspx page uses the right `.cs` class as a `Page.CodeBehind`?

Comment: Are other events on other controls working?

Comment: How is this related to `javascript`. I'd use the `OnCommand` event.

Comment: Javascript was by mistaken

Comment: No other controls in the page requires onClick

Comment: yes this is inside GridView

Comment: On the first line of your aspx file, does the attribute "CodeFile" have the correct name of your .cs file?

Comment: CodeBehind="Blog.aspx.cs" this attribute is like this and this is fine

Comment: And if you go to Design view, than double click the button, does it redirect you to your existing event? or create another?

Comment: @Koen. 
This control is in GridView so in the design view I cannot click on this particular control. But for just checking I added this control outside of the GridView then in design view when I double clicked on it, it went to the code behind and created a new event because I didn't give OnClick event in the tag. But again when running the page Compilation error is coming.

Comment: @user3837889 can you try changing CodeBehind to CodeFile?

Comment: thank you so much Koen it worked.. Post your comment as an answer so that I can check on that :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the first line of your aspx code Change

> CodeBehind=""

to

> CodeFile =""